# "Unknown column" when joining table on itself using an alias

Tags: mysql

My table `TermSeeAlso` has two INT columns: `FromTermID` and `ToTermID`.

I want to find pairs of rows that are each other's inverse, such as the pair { (from 2 to 5), (from 5 to 2) }.

I wrote this query:

```
select * from TermSeeAlso a
join TermSeeAlso b on b.ID > a.ID
and a.FromTermID = b.ToTermID
and b.FromTermID = a.ToTermID
```

- Why does it give this error? "#1054 - Unknown column 'a.ID' in 'on clause'".
- What query will achieve the results I want?

Comment: Is there an ID column? Or are there only the two columns you mentioned?

Comment: ID is the primary key.

Comment: Post the create statement of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I'm an idiot. I was certain the primary key `ID` existed but it doesn't. Sorry.